# Is it possible to have one section of a border to change colors while the rest stays the same color?

Tags: html, css

I want the menu below to under the whole entire menu have a black border and to have the part of the border that is hovered on to turn #19A3FF. Right now it has a gap between the where it says about and contact and I want that particular section to have a black border but not to change colors when that particular section is hovered on. Thank you for responding.

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul .has-sub {
    z-index: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul .menu1 {
  border-bottom: solid black;
}
#cssmenu ul .menu1:hover {
  border-bottom: solid #19A3FF;
  padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: border-color .3s linear; /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
     -moz-transition: border-color .3s linear; /* FF3.7+ */
       -o-transition: border-color .3s linear; /* Opera 10.5 */
          transition: border-color .3s linear;
}
#cssmenu ul .right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li {
  color: white;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#cssmenu {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background: #F5F5F5;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 17px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 35px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.15);
  padding: 11px 15px;
  width: 170px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background: #333333;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='menu1'><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
   <li class='menu1 has-sub'><a href='#'>Products</a>
      <ul>
         <li class='sub-in-sub'><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class='sub-in-sub'><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='menu1'><a href='#'>About</a></li>
   <li class='menu1 right'><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `box-shadow` property and `inset` shadow to create one side inner border that will not interfere with the box model. For example, remove the `border-bottom` properties and add:

```
#cssmenu > ul {
    box-shadow: 0 -3px 0 0 black inset;
}

#cssmenu ul .menu1:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 -3px 0 0 #19a3ff inset;
  padding: 0;
  transition: box-shadow .3s linear;
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0ymprf8n/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code is not complete. Missing the first chunk of the file, I hope I am not missing any CSS.

Added the following line to the unordered list element:

```
  border-bottom: solid black;
```

Added the following line to the first level list items:

```
#cssmenu ul .menu1 {
  margin-bottom: -3px;
}
```

This will also push the menu down to allow you to see the highlighted border when the menu is displayed.